# Is there anything for Python typing that is equivalent to TypeScript's `keyof` to make a Literal

Tags: python, typescript, types, type-hinting

In TypeScript, we have the ability to create a "literal" type based on the keys of an object:

```js
const tastyFoods = {
  pizza: '',
  burger: '',
  iceCream: '',
  fries: '',
  taco: '',
  sushi: '',
  spaghetti: '',
  donut: '',
  cookie: '',
  chicken: '',
} as const;

type TastyFoodsKeys = keyof typeof tastyFoods;
// gives us:
// type TastyFoodsKeys = "pizza" | "burger" | "iceCream" | "fries" | "taco" | "sushi" | "spaghetti" | "donut" | "cookie" | "chicken"
```

Is there an equivalent in Python (3.10+ is fine) for creating type hints based on a dict? E.g.,

```py
from typing import Literal

tasty_foods = {
  "pizza": '',
  "burger": '',
  "iceCream": '',
  "fries": '',
  "taco": '',
  "sushi": '',
  "spaghetti": '',
  "donut": '',
  "cookie": '',
  "chicken": '',
}

TastyFoodsKeys = Literal[list(tasty_foods.keys())]
# except that doesn't work, obviously
```

Comment: Possibly an XY problem. I'm not terribly familiar with TypeScript (or Javascript), but it's my understanding that there are several different Python constructs (dicts, classes, enums, etc) for use cases that are all handled by objects in TypeScript.

Comment: @chepner it's a way to define a type from a compile-time constant in the source code rather than having to explicitly spell out the type and then annotate the value with it.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, but I'm suggesting the compile-time constant shouldn't be a `dict` in Python.

Comment: @chepner agreed, TS won't let you do that with Maps either for the same reason.

Comment: Fundamentally, Python's type system is a nominal class-based system. There is *some* support for structural typing, but nowhere near the depth you get in TypeScript, which is at its core structurally typed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not. You need to define the `Literal` type statically:

```
TastyFoodsKeys = Literal["pizza", "burger"]
```

You can, however, use <strike>`TastyFoodsKeys.__args__` to then define your `dict`.</strike>

```
tasty_foods = dict(zip(TastyFoodsKeys.__args__, ['', '']))
```

**The `__args__` attribute is not documented, so use at your own risk.**

As pointed out in a comment, you can use `typing.get_args` (which *is* documented) instead of accessing `__args__` directly:

```
tasty_foods = dict(zip(typing.get_args(TastyFoodsKeys), ['', '']))
```

---

You might, however, not want to use a `dict` at all. Perhaps what you really want is an enumerated type.

```
from enum import StrEnum


class TastyFood(StrEnum):
    PIZZA = ''
    BURGER = ''
    # etc
```

Comment: Just fyi, there is no need to use the internal undocumented `__args__` attribute. You can use [`typing.get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) for that purpose.

Comment: */puts another nickel in the "forgot about `typing.get_args`" jar.* Hawaiian vacation, here I come!